# Laravel DOMPDF cannot read absolute image path

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am using https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package for Laravel 5.5 to generate PDF. One thing I cannot get pass is rendering the image in PDF using Laravel's helper function such as e.g. asset(), url() etc. I am using the function because I have had bad experiences when the web is hosted not using the helper functions, or you might say using relative source for the image.

For example my code looks like this in **template-pdf.blade.php** :

```
<p><img src="storage/photos/9/pdm SIM_AKADEMIK.png" alt="" /></p>
```

It works. The image shows in the PDF. The image location is in the public folder of Laravel. But if I used

```
<p><img src="{{asset('storage/photos/9/pdm SIM_AKADEMIK.png')}}" alt="" /></p>
```

The image shows up in the browser, but once it's generated to PDF, it takes forever with an error message

> PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

That is only for 1 picture. No I don't want to increase my execution time settings.

What is the workaround?

Yes I do have enable_remote enabled

Comment: What ist your setting of [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) in your `php.ini`? If you reference the source with twig's `asset` function, the image is loaded via HTTP and not directly from the filesystem.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have fixed it, for some reason It took a really long time if I used php artisan serve. But I then deployed it locally through apache and it worked fine.